# Strange error on list initialization

Tags: java, generics

A friend of mine asked me if I could help him find out the reason behind an error he is getting on a piece of code and **most importantly** why the error disappears when he add some piece of code. I've looked into the docs about the classes and couldn't find out the reason too.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /**
        * This line shows this compilation error in eclipse:
        * Type mismatch: cannot convert from 
        *     List<Class<? extends JComponent&Accessible>> 
        *          to List<Class<? extends JComponent>>
        */
        List<Class<? extends JComponent>> listComp = Arrays.asList(JTabbedPane.class, 
                                                                   JPanel.class);

        /**
        * This one compiles fine and the difference is that
        * he added JComponent.class on the list and the 
        * code is working fine
        */
        List<Class<? extends JComponent>> listComp2 = Arrays.asList(JTabbedPane.class, 
                                                                    JPanel.class, 
                                                                    JComponent.class);
    }

}
```

As you can see, the only difference is that on the second list variable we have added the `JComponent.class` and the error goes away.

Why is that?

**Update**

We are using Java JDK 7 update 80

**Update 2**

Another friend suggested this piece of code and it also works:

```
List<Class<? extends JComponent>> listComp = 
      new ArrayList<Class<? extends JComponent>> ( Arrays.asList( JTabbedPane.class, 
                                                                  JPanel.class));
```

Comment: Both compile just fine for me in IntelliJ with Java 8.

Comment: Hmmm, perhaps some sort of bug on jdk 7? O.O

Comment: Type inference was changed in Java 8, the answer is probably somewhere in [this section of the jls](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.7)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can duplicate this issue in Java 7, but when I switch to Java 8, the error is no longer given.  Also, if I stay in Java 7, but I give a type argument to `Arrays.asList`, the error is no longer given.

```
List<Class<? extends JComponent>> listComp =
    Arrays.<Class<? extends JComponent>>asList(JTabbedPane.class, JPanel.class);
```

Java will attempt to determine the target type of the return of `Arrays.asList`.  Apparently, both `JTabbedPane` and `JPanel` extend `JComponent` and implement `Accessible`.  However, `JComponent` doesn't implement `Accessible`.  The result is the most complete, specific type the compiler can get in common from all of the types.  For your first example, the inferred type is `List<Class<? extends JComponent & Accessible>>`, because both arguments fit that type.  When you add `JComponent`, the inferred type is now `List<Class<? extends JComponent>>` and that matches `listComp`, allowing it to compile in Java 7.

Java 8 features improved [target type inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html).  That tutorial's example is of `Collections.emptyList` being passed to a method requiring a `List<String>`.  In Java 7, the inferred type would be `List<Object>` and a compilation error would occur.  However, in Java 8, the inferred type is `List<String>`, matching the method's parameter, and the code compiles.

This isn't quite the same example as your code, but it's close enough that I believe that in general, Java 8's improved target type inference explains why the code compiles with that version.

Comment: That's the catch: `The result is the most complete, specific type the compiler can get in common from all of the types` Thank you, wonderfull explanation.

Comment: This should work too:  `... = Arrays.asList((JComponent) JTabbedPane.class, JPanel.class);`

Comment: Hi @StephenC, are you using java 8? Here with java 7 update 80 I get this error with your code: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Serializable> to List<Class<? extends JComponent>>`